# how to update parse user dictionary object in swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, nsdictionary, pfuser

I have created a Parse user with various Objects such as File, Dictionary , String Objects. I have attached my Parse user object for your reference.

Can anyone help in understanding how to update user's dictionary object?

I am able to access my user dictionary object But not sure how to update my current user dictionary object.

**Working Code:**

1. Able to update user's string object where email is user string Object

   PFUser.currentUser()?.setValue("newEmail", forKey: "email")
2. Able to access dictionary object, where location is user dictionary(personalObjKey) string object

   self.lblLocation.text = user?.valueForKey("personalObjKey")?.objectForKey("location") as? String

**Not Working**

```
PFUser.currentUser()?.setValue("newLocation", forKey: valueForKey("personalObjKey")?.objectForKey("location") as! String)
```

**Error**

valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key personalObjKey.'

Parse User Object

[image]

Comment: Any idea ?    what should be forKey in this case. PFUser.currentUser()?.setValue("New York", forKey: ?

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. I could have accessed Dictionary object first and then its easy to set users dictionary object value.

```
PFUser.currentUser()?.valueForKey("personalObjKey")?.setValue("newLocation", forKey: "location")
```